# Looping several directories AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I need to get a file list in .csv from several directories, I have this script now, I only need to add more directories, is this at all possible?

```
FileList := "File FullPath,Base name,TimeLastModified"
Loop, \\DEFRA1SPDB054\Exports\*.*,0,1
If SubStr(A_LoopFileTimeCreated, 1, 8) = SubStr(A_Now, 1, 8) ;
{
  FormatTime, last_time_modified, %A_LoopFileTimeModified%, MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
  FileList .= "`n" . A_LoopFileFullPath . "," . A_LoopFileName . "," . last_time_modified
}
FileAppend,%FileList%,FileList.csv
Run, excel.exe "FileList.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you could do this for example:

```
folders := "
(
C:\Users\User\Documents\My Cool Folder1
C:\Users\User\Documents\My Cool Folder2
C:\Users\User\Documents\My Cool Folder3
C:\Users\User\Documents\My Cool Folder4
)"

FileList := "File FullPath,Base name,TimeLastModified"

for each, folder in StrSplit(folders, "`n", "`r")
{
    Loop, Files, % folder "\*.*", FR
    {
        if (SubStr(A_LoopFileTimeCreated, 1, 8) = SubStr(A_Now, 1, 8))
        {
            FormatTime, last_time_modified, % A_LoopFileTimeModified, % "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            FileList .= "`n" A_LoopFileFullPath "," A_LoopFileName "," last_time_modified
        }
    }
}

FileAppend, % FileList, % "FileList.csv"
Run, % "excel.exe ""FileList.csv"""
```

I just simply defined some folders in a string `folders` (using a continuation section<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation-section)</sup>), and then looped through each folder passing the folder into a file loop<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm#new)</sup>.

Also, I ditched the legacy syntax/commands from your script.
You were for example using the deprecated file loop, or were referring to variables via legacy `%variable%`, etc.